# Mui Typography alignment based on breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way for me to change my Typography align property based on the pre-defined breakpoints?

For example:

```
<Typography
 align={{ xs: 'left', sm: 'left', md: 'left', lg: 'right', xl: 'right' }}>
```

The following will cause my page to display nothing but white. I usually use that syntax to work with margins in the Box class and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the Typography `align` attribute with an object.

As specified in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#props) for the Typography component, the `align` attribute can only be `'inherit' | 'left' | 'center' | 'right' | 'justify'`.

Instead, you could use the [`withWidth`](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/#withwidth-) HOC:

> Sometimes you might want to change the React rendering tree based on the breakpoint value. We provide a **withWidth()** higher-order component for this use case.

`withWidth` injects a `width` property into your component that gives you access to the current breakpoint value. This allows you to render different props or content based on screen size.

```js
function ResponsiveTypography({ width }) {
  // This is equivalent to theme.breakpoints.down("md")
  const isSmallScreen = /xs|sm|md/.test(width);
  const typographyProps = {
    align: isSmallScreen ? "left" : "right"
  };
  return (
    <Typography {...typographyProps}>
      Some text
    </Typography>
  );
}

export default withWidth()(ResponsiveTypography);
```

Answer (score 2):

With MUI v5, I found that `sx` prop has the ability to do breakpoints without importing the `theme` object (like in @atazmin's answer).

The breakpoints are mobile-first and get translated to `min-width` Media Queries. You can specify the starting value with `xs` and change it by breakpoint using `lg` and up.

```
<Typography
  sx={{
    textAlign: {
      xs: 'left',
      lg: 'right',
    },
  }}
>
```

Comment: This is the best current answer!

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me, MUI v5:

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
```

...

```
const theme = useTheme();
```

...

```
<Typography
  sx={{
  textAlign: 'center',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      textAlign: 'left',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('xl')]: {
      textAlign: 'right',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.between('sm', 'md')]: {

    }
    [theme.breakpoints.not('md')]: {
    }
  }}
>
```

Breakpoints API
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/